# Wizard Installer for a Webpart

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Webpart for a Sharepoint 2010, and I would like to create a "Wizard Installer" for this webpart, that a customer can install to his own Sharepoint Server.

What is the easiest way to do it?

(Now only know how to install via stsadm.exe, but I'm looking for something more user-friendly)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [SharePoint Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/).

-- edit: it is for SharePoint 2007, but a 2010 version is in development.

Comment: Its not too difficult to change to support 2010 whilst waiting for 'official' 2010 version (which seems to have stalled) or you could offer your help to project lead - http://vojtan.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/sharepoint-solution-installer-support-for-sp2010/